# How can I GROUP a LINQ query that includes multiple joined tables with ambiguous column names?

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, join, group-by

Here is my SQL-Query that I want to convert to LINQ:

```
SELECT artikel.id, charge.id
from Lots charge
JOIN Product artikel on charge.artikel = artikel.id
JOIN StorageQuantity_TAB lmengeTAB on charge.id = lmengeTAB.charge
JOIN StorageQuantity lmenge on lmengeTAB.id = lmenge.id
GROUP BY artikel.id, charge.id
```

That´s what I got so far:

```
var query = (from charge in Lots
            join artikel in PartProducts on charge.Artikel equals artikel.Id
            join lmengeTAB in StorageQuantity_TABs on charge.Id equals lmengeTAB.Charge
            join lmenge in StorageQuantities on lmengeTAB.Id equals lmenge.Id
                select new
                {
                    artikel.Id,
                    chargeID = charge.Id,
                }).ToList();
```

So how do I include that GROUP BY statement?

Comment: Use query variable and do a groupby

Comment: What's wrong with `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Comment: (..).Distinct();

Comment: Thanks guys, never heard of the Distinct() Method before!

Comment: You might find my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) helpful.